# android Bluetooth low energy(BLE) onlescan

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to do a BLE application in android and I am unable to figure out why onLeScan() function is not being called.

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
   Log.d(Tag,"in scanLeDevice");
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        Log.d(Tag,"Scanning Done");
        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}


// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        Log.e(Tag,"Scan device rssi is " + rssi);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Logcat:

```
 01-22 15:34:02.449:     D/MainActivity(32531):      in scanLeDevice    
    01-22 15:34:02.449:     D/MainActivity(32531):      Scanning Done
    01-22 15:34:02.449:     D/BluetoothAdapter(32531):  startLeScan(): null
    01-22 15:34:02.453:     D/BluetoothAdapter(32531):  onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
    01-22 15:34:09.005:     D/MainActivity(32531):      in scanLeDevice
    01-22 15:34:09.005:     D/BluetoothAdapter(32531):  stopLeScan()
```

Comment: make sure there are ble devices around and the bluetooth of your device is enabled, also..which device and o.s.? pls post more code, parts in relevance to your question, right now there is only a loop with 1 if between logcat writes of *in scanLeDevice* and *Scanning Done*

Comment: Both devices were discoverable but still its not working

Comment: The devices are not being scanned after we click the scan button.Is there any fix to this problem?

Comment: Which device and what o.s. are you using

Comment: The devices are Motorola MotoG and HTC ONE E8. The OS is Android 4.4.4

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<service android:name=".bluetooth.BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true" />
```

Also you should initialize the Bluetooth adapter through `BluetoothManager`:

```
if (!mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}

// Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
// BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need BOTH of the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml in order to scan for devices:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```